# How can i quickly resize a form after screen rotation?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resize, scaling, tablet

I'm writing a full screen program for windows tablets that needs to resize all of its controls to fit the screen, regardless of rotation.

right now i'm using the following:

```
    Private Sub CreateOrder_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
        Dim widthMultiplier As Decimal = (Me.Width * 0.99) / itemsPanel.Width 'this panel is 99% as tall as the form initially, and 80% as tall
        Dim heightMultiplier As Decimal = (Me.Height * 0.8) / itemsPanel.Height

        resizeEverything(Me.Controls, widthMultiplier, heightMultiplier)
End Sub

Private Sub resizeEverything(ByRef container As Object, ByVal widthMultiplier As Decimal, ByVal heightMultiplier As Decimal)

        For Each screenItem In container
            screenItem.location = New Point(screenItem.location.x * widthMultiplier, screenItem.location.y * heightMultiplier)
            screenItem.size = New Size(screenItem.width * widthMultiplier, screenItem.height * heightMultiplier)
            checkIfFont(screenItem, widthMultiplier)
            If screenItem.GetType() = (New Panel).GetType Then
                resizeEverything(screenItem.controls, widthMultiplier, heightMultiplier)
            End If
        Next     
End Sub

Private Sub checkIfFont(ByRef viewObject As Object, ByVal multiplier As Decimal)
        Dim fontCarriers() As Object = {New RichTextBox, New Label, New TextBox, New ListBox, New DateTimePicker, New ComboBox}
        For Each controlType In fontCarriers
            If viewObject.GetType = controlType.GetType Then
                controlType = viewObject
                Dim myFont As Font = controlType.font
                Dim newFont As Font = New Font(myFont.Name, myFont.Size * multiplier, myFont.Style)
                viewObject.font = newFont
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

This has proven to be far too resource intensive for some of the tablets I've had to put it on.

I havent used Autoscale because the form needs to 'squish' a bit when the tablet is used in portrait mode, and as far as i'm aware, autoscale maintains aspect ratio.

So how can i do this without grinding through and resizing each control?

Comment: I think it's enough to configure your controls `Anchor` and `Dock` properties and use `Panel`, `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` where you need with suitable configurations.

Comment: Depending on what type of animation/transition you want to show, you need to put this in between some `BeginLayout` and `EndLayout` blocks so the screen does not refresh with every control resize.

Comment: that would be a plus.